# Android: Non-transparent text on transparent image

Tags: android, image, text, transparent

I need to put text on transparent image, but my text goes transparent too.

Update: I have an Activity background which is a picture, than I have LinearLayout with background as transparent picture, and in that Layout I need a TextView with text without transparency.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/img_background"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="team.com.ContactUsActivity">
>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutContactUsData"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:background="@drawable/img_contact_us"
    android:alpha="0.4"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:text="Phone: 111-111-111"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: set the Alpha on your TextView to 1

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work. I still get transparent text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `android:alpha`.
If you don't, the TextView will inherit the container property, causing it to be transparent, instead of fully visible.

TextView backgrounds are transparent by default.

Comment: Yes, but I have an Activity background which is a picture, than I have LinearLayout with background as transparent picture, and in that Layout I need a TextView with text without transparency.

Comment: a layout is transparent, unless you don't set a background picture to it. let the transparency belong to the picture, **not to the layout**! You shouls know that **PNG files do have an alpha channel**.

Comment: That should do. Thanks.